# Actionbar Sherlock tabs and navigation list

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using sherlockbar. How do I add a ActionBar bar with tabs and a navigation list? As this image from Google Maps

[image]

In my code, I can not seem to set two behaviors for ActionBar

```
ActionBar bar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the opt navigation (Meus Lugares) are added using the menu onCreateMenu .
The other are Tabs which you add using 
bar.AddTab()